# Why can't twilio calls survive a *71 carrier call forward ? Is it some kind of loop protection?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I have a number provisioned in twilio that does a simple call forwarding twiml bin.

The call is forwarded to a physical SIM number:

```
<Response>
<Dial>
+1-333-333-3333
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Then on handset I dialed *71,212-555-1212 where "212-555-1212" is a DIFFERENT number I have provisioned in twilio. This is called provisional forwarding at the carrier and it means that if the handset do not pick up after 4-5 rings it will forward it to the number I specified (212-555-1212).

If I call the first twilio number it forwards as expected and the handset ringing.

But then after the 4-5 rings the carrier call forward occurs and the call is terminated - the call is not passed onto the second twilio number. Provisional call forwarding fails.

Why is this happen ?

I think maybe twilio can tell this is a call loop and thinks it is a mistake or negative in some ways ? Or this is just a bug I have discovered and there is no meaning to it ?

Comment: You'd be better off filing a support case with Twilio or checking their knowledge base.